# Pusher error: 404 NOT FOUND when using laravel

Tags: laravel, pusher

I'm using laravel 9 and I'm trying to get my localhost to use pusher, but when I test I get Pusher error: 404 NOT FOUND in my logs. this is a portion of the stack trace

> [2022-09-02 14:22:38] local.ERROR: Pusher error: 404 NOT FOUND
> . {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException(code: 0): Pusher error: 404 NOT FOUND
> . at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/PusherBroadcaster.php:164)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting broadcast is not enough to create an integration.

In first step install pusher:
`composer require pusher/pusher-php-server`

And after that, try run this command:
`php artisan config:cache`

Source:
https://pusher.com/tutorials/web-notifications-laravel-pusher-channels/

Comment: I actually didn't run `php artisan config:cache` I thought that I had run that command but it looks like I was wrong

Comment: I am very happy that I can help you :)

Comment: This did not resolve the error for me.